# Can't get Splashscreen on flash builder to work

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I'm trying to use an image for my splashscreen on flash builder 4.7 but it doesn't seem to work. 
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:TabbedViewNavigatorApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                              xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                              splashScreenImage="DynamicSplashScreen.mxml">
<s:ViewNavigator label="Menu" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.MenuView"/>
<s:ViewNavigator label="Search" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.SearchView"/>
<s:ViewNavigator label="Location" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.LocationView"/>
<s:ViewNavigator label="List" width="100%" height="100%" firstView="views.ListView"/>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
```

and for the dynamicSplash screen.mxml it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SplashScreenImage xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">   
<s:SplashScreenImageSource dpi="160" aspectRatio="portrait" source="@Embed('/images/Random.png')"/>   
</s:SplashScreenImage>
```

i'm new to this, so i'm sorry if the answer is simple.

Answer (score 0):

For splashscreens I use the following code:

```
splashScreenScaleMode="letterbox"
splashScreenImage="@Embed('assets/splashScreen.png')"
```

You will only need to change the image path with your own.